# Как пересобрать видео, содержащее аудио дорожку в формате TrueHD+AC3 core с помощью FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

Хотел пересобрать BDMV видео с помощью FFmpeg в файл MKV.
Видео содержит две дорожки в формате TrueHD + AC3 core.
VLC видит эти дорожки как одну. Воспроизводит корректно.

Сижу под убунтой. Пробовал tsMuxer. Он с задачей справляется корректно, только делать MKV не умеет.

Пробовал кодировать, указывая как оба потока в -map, так и первый из них.
Пробовал сохранять их порядковые номера в файле.
В конечном итоге пробовал не менять контейнер, а пересобрать в ts, как было.

Например:

```
ffmpeg -i Final\ fantasy\ \(2009\).ts -c copy -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 tmp.ts
```

Никаких ошибок FFmpeg не выдаёт, только видит дорожки trueHD и AC3 core как отдельные. В выходном файле получается две разные дорожки. VLC видит в результирующем файле тоже две дорожки.

Вывод ffprobe для исходного файла:

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'Final fantasy (2009).ts':
  Duration: 02:06:33.60, start: 4200.000000, bitrate: 29796 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Stream #0:0[0x1011]: Video: h264 (High) (HDMV / 0x564D4448), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 47.95 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1100](eng): Audio: truehd (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), s32 (24 bit)
    Stream #0:2[0x1100]: Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 640 kb/s
    Stream #0:3[0x1101](jpn): Audio: truehd (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), s32 (24 bit)
    Stream #0:4[0x1101]: Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 640 kb/s
    Stream #0:5[0x1200](eng): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle ([144][0][0][0] / 0x0090), 1920x1080
    Stream #0:6[0x1201](eng): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle ([144][0][0][0] / 0x0090), 1920x1080
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сохранить связь дорожек, если это возможно?

Answer (score 1):

Может мой ответ поможет кому-то, кто в похожей ситуации...

Пока ждал ответа на свой вопрос, я пошел другим путём.
Стал искать ответ на вопрос: а надо ли сохранять эти две дорожки вместе?
Оказывается не надо.

TrueHD не содержит в себе никакого ядра. Два трека добавлены в одну дорожку, чтобы BluRay плеер, который не обязан поддерживать TrueHD, мог вместо него проиграть AC3.

Если намерения смотреть на аппаратном плеере нет, то можно просто оставить TrueHD дорожку. Что, в итоге, я и сделал...